# Is there a way to get a report of Pardot Salesforce engage alerts?

Tags: pardot

Basically is there any other way, ideally a typical SF tabular report, to view the data from the alert tiles from the image below.

Googling I can only find reports regarding user adoption and metrics around emails sent rather than the alerts themselves.

Thanks

[image]